# tar excluding parent directories and creating tarball on remote host

Tags: tar

I have a host where an application creates model directories/files. I want to tar up those files and send it over to another host for DR backup.

So far I have the following:

```
sudo tar -zcvf - /mnt/nfsshared | ssh app@<ip-address> "cat > /data/models/models_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).tar.gz" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This command will tar up all directories and files in /mnt/nfsshared and create the tarball on the remote host under /data/models/
However, I want to exclude the the /mnt/nfsshared/ parent directories and just tar up the directories/files in the /nfsshared directory.

I know I could cd to /mnt/nfshared and tar up all files.

I can also do this command

```
sudo -C /mnt/nfsshared -zcvf | ssh app@<ip-address> "cat > /data/models/models_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).tar.gz" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

which would only tar up directories/files under nfsshared. However, what argument would I pass to the command: -zcvf
I can't use a tarball name since the tarball gets created on the remote host.

Within /mnt/nfsshared/ I have multiple directories containing additional subdirectories and files.

```
/mnt/nfsshared/model1/files 
              /model2/files 
              /model3/submodel1/files 
                     /submodel2/files 
                     /submodel3/files 
              /model4/submodel1/files 

I want only to tar up the model, submodel directories and the files I want to exclude the /mnt/nfsshared directories

Cheers,
Roland
```

Comment: Any one have any input??

Comment: cd to directory and then tar. Here is similar question about zip: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182036/101265

Comment: thank you @RomeoNinov, yes cd to the directory is a possibility. Using the -C flag gets around the this. However, within /mnt/nfsshared/ I have multiple directories containing additional subdirectories and files.    
 ```/nfsshared/model1/files
                     /model2/files
                    /model3/submodel1/files
              /submodel2/files
                                 /submodel3/files
                    /model4/submodel1/files
```
I want only to tar up the model, submodel directories and the files
I want to exclude the /mnt/nfsshared directories

Comment: Please add this to the question. ANd be aware if those directories are not unified you should do this by hand (IMHO)